# Save range value from range_image as .png file

Tags: c++, ros, point-cloud-library

robotics community. I am a newbie C++ programmer and am learning ROS.

Currently, I am trying to create a depth map from range_image class. I found a short answer from ROS mailing list that showing how to do [this](http://www.pcl-users.org/how-to-save-range-image-td4042471.html). However, it seems like the method

```
pcl::io::saveRgbPNGFile (const std::string &file_name, const unsigned char *rgb_image, int width, int height);
```

does not exist anymore, since I got the error below during compile

```
error: ‘saveRgbPNGFile’ is not a member of ‘pcl::io’
  pcl::io::saveRgbPNGFile("ha.png", rgb_image, width, height);
```

Below is part of the snippet of the relevant part for creating `range_image` instance and converting `range` field to .png file

**Code Snippet**

`void ScanHandler::finalize_scan()` is responsible to convert point cloud to range image

```
void ScanHandler::finalize_scan(){
...
pcl::RangeImage rangeImg;
rangeImg.createFromPointCloud(*m_pcloud, angularResolution, 
                              maxAngleWidth, maxAngleHeight,
                              sensorPose, coordinate_frame, 
                           noiseLevel, minRange, borderSize);
float* data = rangeImg.getRangesArray();
publish_range_img(data, rangeImg.width, rangeImg.height);
}
```

`void ScanHandler::publish_range_img(float* data, int width, int height)` is responsible to publish the range image (which is an image composed by range value instead of pcl::RangeImage instance)

```
void ScanHandler::publish_range_img(float* data, int width, int height){
    sensor_msgs::Image msg;
    pcl::toROSMsg(&data, msg); // ERROR!!!!!
    msg.header.frame_id = m_reference_frame();
    msg.width = width;
    msg.height = height;

    m_range_img_pub.publish(msg);
    unsigned char* rgb_image = pcl::visualization::FloatImageUtils::getVisualImage (data, width, height); 
    pcl::io::saveRgbPNGFile("ha.png", rgb_image, width, height); // ERROR
}
```

**Problem**

Currently, the main problem is that I could not successfully save range value to .png and I failed to publish the float array whose element to the topic as well

I am hoping someone could point me to a right direction, since I already try everything I can find on Internet, and still it does not work. I am running out of idea.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: [`pcl::toROSMsg`](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.8.0/namespacepcl.html#a6112d33a74897d53fde1fdbbd79a2c64) takes a `pcl::PointCloud` as input, but you are giving it `float**` as input.  
To fix the `saveRgbPNGFile` error, have you tried including `<pcl/io/png_io.h>`?

Comment: Hi! `<pcl/io/png_io.h>` do the trick and my code can be compile now if I comment out the msgs part. Now, I try to figure out msgs part.